# How to precisely show that $\sqrt{z}$ can be defined on an obtuse sector?

Tags: complex-analysis

During reading a solution to a question asking to find a map between to domains, after the author transformed $A=\{|z|<1\}\setminus\{x\in \Bbb{R}:a\le x \le 1\}$ ($-1<a<1$) to $B=\{|z|<1\}\setminus\{x\in\Bbb{R}:0\le x\le 1\}$ (which I don't know what to call other than "(obtuse)sector"), I got lost as they simply stated that there is a branch of $\sqrt{z}$ defined on $B$, and I don't see what it is easily derived from. What is the canonical way to present it? I got confused pretty quickly using $\log$.

Comment: Can’t you describe $B$ as $\{re^{i\theta}: 0<r<1, 0<\theta<2\pi\}$? On that domain, square root is pretty easily definable.

Comment: Why, then, can't it be described in all $\Bbb{D}$?

Comment: What I am trying to understand is where a problem might arise if one doesn't use a branch...

Comment: Doesn’t your $\sqrt z$ jump when you go from $\frac14+i\varepsilon$ to $\frac14-i\varepsilon$?

Comment: You can define the square root function on any open set where you can define the logarithm (by $\sqrt{z} := \exp ( \frac{1}{2} Log z)$ and the most general domain where you can define the Logarithm is any simply connected open which does not contain the origin (and $B$ is an example of such a domain).